# Access property of UserControl on MasterPage from content page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

Trying to get the value of a property on a usercontrol displayed on a masterpage from a content page but the value is not correct.

MasterPage APSX:

```
    <div style="float: left">
        <uc:SessionSummary ID="SessionSummary1" runat="Server" />
    </div>
```

MasterPage CS:

```
    public SessionSummary SessionSummaryControl
    {
        get { return (SessionSummary)this.FindControl("SessionSummary1"); }
    }
```

UserControl:

```
    public bool RejectedBatches
    {
        get { return lblRejectedBatches.Text.ToUpper().Trim() == "YES" ; }
    }
```

ContentPage ASPX:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="MAASDefault.master" %>
<%@ Reference VirtualPath="MAASDefault.master" %>
```

ContentPage CS:

```
bool _value = Master.SessionSummaryControl.RejectedBatches;
```

_value is always false even though the text displayed on the control is 'Yes'

Not seeing what I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated.

edit-
Ok here is my delima. I have checked several page events and found one that will give me the value. But, since the property is on the masterpage and the masterpage is a child control of the content page the value is only available after the Page_Load event of the content page. I need to render controls in the content page based on this value from the master. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try overriding the OnLoadComplete of the page, at this stage of the page life cycle the control will be loaded with the data.

```
protected override void OnLoadComplete(EventArgs e)
        {
            bool _value = Master.SessionSummaryControl.RejectedBatches;
            base.OnLoadComplete(e);

        }
```

Comment: I think I tried that event but the problem is that the _value is obtained to late to allow it to decide what will be loaded on the content form in it's page load event

Comment: Can you give me more information about what you want to do with this value that must be done in the page load and not in the page load completed ?!

Comment: I have a value in a control on the masterpage that is loaded during setup. This value notifies the user it they have items that need to be dealt with immediately. So when they click the link to go into the correct form I know what data needs to be displayed by default to the user. I know there are several ways to accomplish the objective, and I do have a working model now however If grabbing the value in this manner is possible I would like to nail it down as I know I will use this in the future.

Comment: That would be because I forgot to move the deterministic logic code from the Page_Load event into the OnLoadComplete event. Thanks Samir. That worked just like I would have expected it to.

Answer (score 1):

When are you calling `Master.SessionSummaryControl.RejectedBatches`? If it's before the user control is data bounded or initialized then you will have this problem.

Please refer to page life cycle to make sure that you are accessing user control late enough.

Comment: Sorry, I should have included that it is in the Page_Load event under if (!Page.IsPostBack) {bool _value = Master.SessionSummaryControl.RejectedBatches;}

Comment: Ok here is my delima. I have checked several page events and found one that will give me the value. But, since the property is on the masterpage and the masterpage is a child control of the content page the value is only available after the Page_Load event of the content page. I need to render controls in the content page based on this value from the master. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably step through this in the debugger to see what's going on.

My best guess is that the text for lblRejectedBatches is getting set sometime after you're trying to load the result into _value